# jQuery book with complete sample application?

Tags: jquery

Is there a book out there that teaches jQuery beginner by using a complete sample application?

Comment: The only book I found, so far, is this (but it's not out yet!): http://www.amazon.com/Practical-Rails-jQuery-Projects/dp/1430218398/ref=sr_1_12?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1294789168&sr=1-12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend [JQuery Enlightement](http://jqueryenlightenment.com/).

Comment: I couldn't find out the site what kind of application they build. Is it more like small example, or do they actually build a "complete" app?

Comment: They don't actually build anything.  It's just the best book out there in my opinion.  They really concentrate on the all the basic concepts and a very easy to follow way, and they do it all with examples.

Comment: Thanks a lot. At $15 it's cheaper than a lot of books out there. I will buy it today. =)

Answer (score 1):

There are several John Resig tutorials, e.g.

[jQuery Demo - Expandable Sidebar Menu](http://vimeo.com/116991)

More of them are listed here: http://www.noupe.com/tutorial/51-best-of-jquery-tutorials-and-examples.html